# Renaming files in the directory based on file names hashable in the excel sheet-PYTHON

Tags: python, excel

I'm creating a python script to rename all the files.

[image]

I have the files saved as these numbers, now to open it and name them was too cumbersome so I thought to create a script for it. I have an excel sheet that **represents the name of the file w.r.t its number.**

[image]

I had to clean the excel first.
Here, some numbers are not present in the excel sheet because of duplicacy and we don't know the state of duplicacy in the directory so those aren't touched.

[image]

I thought hashing would help me here but I'm facing some bugs. Please help me out.
Here's my code

```py
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Kirti\Downloads\Book2.xlsx')
data=data[:-1]
data['Number']=data['Number'].astype(int)
hs=data.set_index('Number')['Name'].to_dict()
```

```py
count=1
import os 
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Kirti\Documents\Notnumbered')
for f in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Kirti\Documents\Notnumbered'):
    try:
        file_name='{}.{}'.format(count,'pdf')
        new_name = '{}.{}'.format(hs[count], 'pdf')
        print(file_name,new_name)
        os.rename(f, new_name)
    except KeyError: 
        count+=1
        continue
    count+=1
```

ERROR:

```
1.pdf ITILST0701 Transition Planning and Support Policy.pdf     # If we see here, the counter didn't 
                                                              #increase and name of the file
                                                              # stayed the first name only. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5f40d4caed55> in <module>
      7         new_name = '{}.{}'.format(hs[count], 'pdf')
      8         print(file_name,new_name)
----> 9         os.rename(f, new_name)
     10     except KeyError:
     11         count+=1

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: '127.pdf' -> 'ITILST0701 Transition Planning and Support Policy.pdf'
```

Why is the counter not increasing? and if the files before 127 were compiled then should've been printed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you use `except` to catch `KeyError` but you get `FileExistsError` so it will not run code in `except` and it will not increase counter. It will simply stop program and display error.

Comment: error shows that  you should check `os.path.exists(...)` before renaming.

Comment: I realised that the problem was occuring because it traversed through files in string sorted manner as, 1,10,11--19,2,20..

Comment: But still, doesn't help @furas please help me find an correct idea for this

Comment: error shows that you aready have file with this name and you have to skip this rename - using `if os.path.exists(...):`. OR you should use `except FileExistsError:` to catch this error.

Answer (score 0):

Error `FileExistsError` shows you that file with this name already exists.

So you should catch this error to continue code

```
    except FileExistsError:
```

like

```
import os   # PEP8: all imports at the beginnig

count = 1   # PEP8: spaces around `=`

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Kirti\Documents\Notnumbered')

for f in os.listdir():  # if you already do `chdir` then you don't have to use full path
    try:
        file_name = '{}.pdf'.format(count)
        new_name = '{}.pdf'.format(hs[count])

        print(file_name, new_name)  # PEP8: space after `,`

        os.rename(f, new_name)
    except KeyError as ex: 
        print('KeyError:', ex)  # it is good to display message with error - to see if there was some problem
    except FileExistsError as ex: 
        print('FileExistsError:', ex)  # it is good to display message with error - to see if there was some problem

    count += 1
```

Or you should check if file already exists and rename only if it doesn't exist

```
    if not os.path.exists(new_name):
        os.rename(f, new_name)
```

like:

```
import os   # PEP8: all imports at the beginnig

count = 1   # PEP8: spaces around `=`

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Kirti\Documents\Notnumbered')

for f in os.listdir():  # if you already do `chdir` then you don't have to use full path
    try:
        file_name = '{}.pdf'.format(count)
        new_name = '{}.pdf'.format(hs[count])

        print(file_name, new_name)  # PEP8: space after `,`

        if not os.path.exists(new_name):
            os.rename(f, new_name)
        else:
            print('File already exists')
    except KeyError as ex: 
        print('KeyError:', ex)  # it is good to display message with error - to see if there was some problem

    count += 1
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)